# chamar variáveis de outra definição e continuar

Tags: ruby

Tenho algumas variáveis que se repetem muito e gostaria de agrupá-las em uma definição, para ser chamada por várias outras definições.

Exemplo:

```rb
module Andre
  module Dialogos

    def self.um
      puts "estou em um"
      self.dois #chamar tudo da definição dois
      puts "#{vogais}"
      puts "estava em dois, agora estou em um."
      self.tres
    end

    def self.dois
      vogais = "estou em dois"
      consoantes = "b, c, d, e, f"
    end

    def self.tres
      puts "estou em tres"
      self.dois #chamar tudo da definição dois
      puts "#{consoantes}"
      puts "estava em dois, voltei para o três"
    end

    self.um
  end
end
```

Neste caso, acontece um erro porque não é possível saber quem é vogais e consoantes, então o código apenas exibe o primeiro puts.

Gostaria de chamar a variável vogais da definição dois e continuar fazendo meus cálculos na definição um.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caso alguém tenha este mesmo problema, resolvi estudando sobre as variáveis e descobri a Class Variable, que é definida por @@.

Neste caso, para o meu código ser funcional, fiz o seguinte:

```
module Andre
  module Dialogos

    def self.um
      puts "estou em um"
      self.dois #chamar tudo da definição dois
      puts "#{@@vogais}"
      puts "estava em dois, agora estou em um."
      self.tres
    end

    def self.dois
      @@vogais = "estou em dois"
      @@consoantes = "b, c, d, e, f"
    end

    def self.tres
      puts "estou em tres"
      self.dois #chamar tudo da definição dois
      puts "#{@@consoantes}"
      puts "estava em dois, voltei para o três"
    end

    self.um
  end
end
```

Agora funciona!!!